# How to find certain value in an array

Tags: java, loops

I am trying to find the first time a certain value appears in an array and increase it. 
Then enter a name into the string array in same spot.

For example I have an `array = {2, 1, 0, 0}` and a `string array = {null, null, null, null}`.

What I am trying to do is check the array for a zero and if one is found, increase its value by 1 and enter a name into the corresponding string array spot. so if the zero is in the 3rd spot in the int array, the user can enter a name into the 3rd spot in the string array.

If I call the method again, it would use the following zero. Any advice how I could do this would be appreciated!

Comment: nothing left to do than implement your description... did you try that?

Comment: What have you tried so far ? Ask a specific question. Don't assume that people will solve your assignments.

Answer (score 2):

You can try: `java.util.Arrays.asList(theArray).indexOf(0)`
This way you can find the position of 0 and then use it for your purpose

Comment: will this work if there are multiple zeros? I want to find the first one

Comment: Here, let me link the documentation for you: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#indexOf%28java.lang.Object%29

Comment: Test it with a sample array and see what you get.. If you get an array of positions instead of a single position, maybe you can try to extract the first value from the returned array of positions.. Not sure.. Just give it a real try..

Answer (score 2):

You would do this:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
for (int i = 0; i <= array1.length; i++) {
    if (array1[i] == 0) {
        array1[i]++;
        String str = s.nextLine();
        array2[i] = str;
    }
}
```

or if you want to use a `JOptionPane` you would replace the `Scanner` lines with `String str = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter A String");`.

Comment: Hi, good answer. I applied some formatting changes (to enable syntax highlighting) and moved the creation of the `Scanner` instance out of the for loop, so it won't be recreated on every iteration. You're free to edit your answer if you don't like my changes. Greetings.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
int index = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < arrayNumbers.size; i++){
  if(arrayNumbers[i] == 0){
     index = i;
     break;
  }
}

arrayNames[index] = newName;
```

Answer (score 0):

The class below creates two arrays  as you provided. At run time the program checks for zeros in the  integer array, array1. If it finds a zero it increments it by one. The index of that element is then used to modify the String array, array2. You decided at runtime what the sting is going to be.

```
public class FindValue {

private int[] array1 = { 2, 1, 0, 0 };
private String[] array2 = { null, null, null, null };



public void checkStuff() {
    for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
        if (array1[i] == 0) {
            array1[i]++;
            System.out.println("Enter string: ");
            Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
            String inputstr = s.nextLine();
            array2[i] = inputstr;

        }

    }

}

public void getIntArray(){
     for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(array1[i]);
    }
}
public void getStrArray(){
    for (int i = 0; i < array2.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(array2[i]);
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    FindValue here = new FindValue();

    here.checkStuff();
    here.getIntArray();
    here.getStrArray();

}
}
```